# Math in SQL query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, math

I have a sql query (SQL server 2005) that's creating a var and doing some math.  The math works when the ticket count is 0 or 250000, but it's not creating a decimal point when the ticket count is any other value.  (It reads 0.)  Here is the query -

```
SELECT ticketCount, ((250000 - ticketCount) / 250000) * 100 AS percentSold 
FROM raffleTickets
```

Where `ticketCount` in the DB is how many tickets of 250000 remain to be sold.  If `ticketCount` is 250000, `percentsold` is 0, which is correct.  If `ticketCount` is 0, `percentSold` is 100, which is correct.  For all other values, `percentSold` is returning 0.

Please help!  Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you're running into integer division issues. As a guess, try appending `.0` to each number.

Comment: Adding .0 to each of the 250000's returns the correct percentages.  Now, how to limit it to one decimal place?  Do I do that in the query as well or in the display?  This is driving an XML file.  Display is:

writer.WriteElementString("percentsold", myReader["percentSold"].ToString());

Comment: writer.WriteElementString("percentsold", ((decimal)myReader["percentSold"]).ToString("N1"));

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does integer division (this varies among databases).

You can easily fix this by putting a decimal point after the constants:

```
SELECT ticketCount, ((250000.0 - ticketCount) / 250000.0) * 100.0 AS percentSold
FROM raffleTickets;
```

If you want the integer portion, then you can `cast()` the result back to an integer.  Alternatively, you can use the [`str()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) function to convert the value of `percentSold` to a string with the appropriate number of decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is correct,

```
PercentSold = (TotalTickets - TicketsRemaining) / TotalTickets
```

But what is the Domain and Range of the above function?  Your numbers are all expressed as integer, but you probably want to calculate using Real.

```
PercentSold = ( ( TotalTickets - TicketsRemaining )*100.0) / (TotalTickets)
```

This forces the calculation to be done in Real.  Languages that know how to declare variables and calculations in specific types (i.e. Domains) can make this clearer, more apparent.

Wanting to represent a real number with a certain precision means you want to perform output formatting.  SqlServer must have a way to specify output format for numbers in the Real Domain.  I defer to [SqlZoo.net](http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/tip177276/sqlserver) for their answer to formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is putting plus or minus 0.0 in your formula.

```sql
SELECT ticketCount, ((250000 - ticketCount - 0.0) / 250000) * 100 AS percentSold 
FROM raffleTickets
```

Comment: The thing is that all numbers are probably integers, and when integers are divided the result is integer too.